# Linq-to-SQL produces bad SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to run a Linq-to-SQL query, but when the query is evaluated, I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  Message=The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.
  Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       at xxx.InventoryPopulator`2.Clear(String barcode) in F:\Projects\C#\xxx\xxx\InventoryPopulator.cs:line 38
       [..etc..]
  InnerException:
```

The debugger shows my query is:

```
SELECT [t0].[SupplierID] AS [Id], [t0].[SupplierSKU] AS [Sku], [t0].[LocalSKU] AS [LocalSku], [t0].[ManufacturersBarcode] AS [Barcode], [t0].[QuantityAvailable]
FROM [inventorySupplier] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ManufacturersBarcode] = @p0
```

And the Linq query which generates the above is:

```
var items = from item in this.supplierItems
            where item.Barcode == barcode
            select item;
```

How do I fix my query?

Comment: Did you run the generated query against your database and see if it runs?

Comment: @Raja, I ran the query in MS Access and it seemed to run fine; no errors or anything were reported.

Comment: As SLaks says Linq to SQL can be used for SQL Server only. Try the provider he suggested.
@SLaks I already gave a +1 for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to SQL can only be used with SQL Server.

To use LINQ against other databases, you need a LINQ provider, such as [this one](http://www.re-motion.org/blogs/team/archive/2009/04/23/introducing-re-linq-a-general-purpose-linq-provider-infrastructure.aspx).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I can use this ...  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Not offhand.  You can also use an off-the-shelf provider, such as http://alinq.org.